Codeium extension in Visual Studio code, suggestions disappear in millisecond
I installed Codeium extension in Visual studio code. When I start typing, the suggestions disappear in millisecond. When I hit the Tab button, the suggestion shows up quick and disappear again in second I can't have the time to accept it or review it.
I disabled all installed extensions in case one was interfering with Codeium extension and I was adjusting the settings below :

My understanding was setting a higher value to the delay will force the suggestions to be visible for longer time But it didn't fix the issue.
Codeium settings on the settings.json file look as below :
{
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
  "security.allowedUNCHosts": [
    "xx.xx.xx.xxxx"
  ],
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "python.experiments.optInto": [],
  "editor.inlineSuggest.showToolbar": "always",
  "codeium.enableConfig": {
    
    "*": true
  },
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 100
}


Any suggestions please what settings am I missing ?

I encountered the same issue, and I was able to resolve it by configuring:
{
  "editor.inlineSuggest.showToolbar": "onHover",
}

